# How to make Line charts developed using svg, responsive

Tags: svg, path, linechart, viewbox

I have created a line chart in which I am setting the width and height of the line chart depending on the size of the container

```
"style": {
                "width": Math.round($('#' + container).width()) + "px",
                "height": Math.round($('#' + container).height()) + "px",
                "border": "1px solid silver",
                "position": "relative",
                "top": "0px"
            },
```

Initially the height and width of the container is 0 and hence the height of the svg is set with some default height and width

```
        defaultHeigth = 500;
        defaultWidth = 1163;
        chartConfiguration.chart.style.height = defaultHeigth;
        chartConfiguration.chart.style.width = defaultWidth;
```

Then while creating the svg I am setting the viewbox as

```
svgEle.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 " + chartConfigOptions.chart.style.width + " " + chartConfigOptions.chart.style.height);

svgEle.setAttribute("width", "100%");
svgEle.setAttribute("height", "100%");
svgEle.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "none");
```

I have tried all sorts of preserveAspectRatio like xMidYMid meet

But in firefox on default load it throws NS_ERROR_FAILURE: and when re-sizing the window size the chart gets rendered perfectly inside the container
In other browsers the chart is rendering but its somewhat distorted(like axis points and values are overlapping) and on resizing the window it renders fine.

Comment: Probably best if you create a runnable example e.g. a stack snippet or a jsfiddle.

Comment: The thing is I cannot share the whole code because it holds copyrights. I am just referring that code.

Comment: Excellent, because we don't want the whole code, we want a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks. I got it resolved. I was making a mistake that I was calling the rendering of line chart before the creation of DOM